# displaying contacts in a UItableview

Tags: iphone

i am able to add contacts (iphone contacts ) to a table view all at once by clicking refresh button in my application .
But i want to add specific contacts to my table view that mean (when i select a contact in the people picker view controller only that contact has to add in my table view can any one please help me how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ABAddressBookRef ab;
ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
int len = (int) ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(ab);
int i;
for(i = 1; i < (len + 1); i++)
{
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab,(ABRecordID) i);
NSString *firstName;
firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

if([firstName isEqualToString:selectedName])
//Add to array
}
```